# Prove that $\mathbb{Z} \times\Bbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

Prove that $\mathbb{Z} \times\Bbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are not isomorphic.

Here by $\mathbb{Z}$ I mean the group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and by $\Bbb Z_2$ I mean the cyclic group of order 2.

This is exercise 2.3.13 part (a) from *Dummit/Foote, Abstract Algebra* - I am aware the solution may be posted somewhere online, but I try to look at full solutions as little as possible for my own understanding.

Here is my general argument. Is this a correct approach, and is it missing any important details?

Let $\Bbb Z_2=\{0,1\}$. The element $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{Z} \times\Bbb Z_2$ has order 2, and since isomorphism preserves order of elements and there exists no integer with order 2, there cannot be an isomorphism between the groups.

Comment: It is correct.${}$

Comment: In a more general context this follows from the uniqueness part of the fundamental theorem on finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: It is correct, but has been discussed often already (see for example [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/prove-z-x-z2-isomorphic-z-q41021642)).

Comment: See also the [solutions](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~cpopescu/Spring2018/103B/103B-HW2.pdf) to homework.

Comment: Indeed, that is why I added my remark about desiring *not* to look at other individuals' full solutions wherever possible.

Comment: So also not to answers here, which would very likely be similar to other individuals' full solutions (actually deleted now, and different).

Comment: Correct. I was looking for verification that my approach is correct, not a full solution.